# how to get Winsock.state in C# .net using Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, winsock

We are implementing VB6 code to c sharp.net for client server communication. In VB6 for communication used Winsock control and checking the client /remote connection status whether is available or not. In C sharp we use tcplistner class and socket class for communication. But we are not able to find out how to check the status of remote/client is connected or not.

Socketing programme, ASP.Net C#, VS2008

VB6 Code

```
'checking socket status

if CommForm.Sock(i).State <> sckClosed then
s="Connection opened"
else
s="Connection closed"
end if

Public Function GetSockStatus()
{
  Select Case CommForm.Sock(i).State
  Case sckClosed
    GetSockStatus = "Closed"
  Case sckOpen
    GetSockStatus = "Open"
  Case sckListening
    GetSockStatus = "Listening"
  Case sckConnectionPending
    GetSockStatus = "Connection pending"
  Case sckResolvingHost
    GetSockStatus = "Resolving host"
  Case sckHostResolved
    GetSockStatus = "Host resolved"
  Case sckConnecting
    GetSockStatus = "Connecting"


}
```

---

C# Code:

For the code CommForm.Sock(i).State <> sckClosed , I tried following in ASP.net C#

```
  if(!client.Connected)
```

where client is sockect object in .net

but I could not find any equivalent code of CommForm.Sock(i).State in .net, there is one .poll which return True/False, but is there any else that can give us socket state as it was in VB6 WinSock.

Comment: Why would you need access to the socket state information? Have you possibly considered using a network library to save yourselves time? I'm the developer of networkComms.net which is supported by both VB and C#.

Comment: @MarcF We are showing the window on server side web page and it displays state of socket. So end user understand the communication progress. 
We haven't used any network library, going thr NetworkComms.net, may be I will have to re-write code since are about to finish project using socket and tcplistener. It would have been nice if we came across when starting project.